# Change color of forest block

Tags: forest

I want to change one of the block's color, but am not sure about how to do it. This is the flowchart I have:

[image]

and the code is..

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{beamer}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{forest}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\setbeamersize{text margin left=2em,text margin right=2em}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[shrink=25]{Results}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    rounded corners, draw, align=center, top color=white, bottom color=blue!20,
    edge+=->,
    l sep'+=10pt,
  }, 
   [This
     [is the forest
       [chart I want ]%want this block green if is possible.. :)
       [but it is not]
     ]
     [working
       [help!]
     ]
   ] 
\end{forest}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How to make the "chart I want" green (with white top also)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add extra options for a specific node by writing a comma followed by the options inside the brackets, e.g. `[foo, draw=red,fill=blue]`, so I guess you want `[chart I want, bottom color=green!20]`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{beamer}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{forest}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\setbeamersize{text margin left=2em,text margin right=2em}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[shrink=25]{Results}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    rounded corners, draw, align=center, top color=white, bottom color=blue!20,
    edge+=->,
    l sep'+=10pt,
  }, 
   [This
     [is the forest
       [chart I want, bottom color=green!20]
       [but it is not]
     ]
     [working
       [help!]
     ]
   ] 
\end{forest}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```