# How to draw the taxonomy tree diagram in latex using forest package?

Tags: forest, trees

I'm trying to draw the following taxonomy tree diagram.  I'm somewhat familiar with latex but completely new to forest package.
[image: Latex Taxonomy diagram using forest package]

I have gone through the answers to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/556831/drawing-taxonomy-diagram-in-latex). However there is no information regarding how to set the colors and edges for the nodes.

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

In this question,

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, there is no information regarding how to set edges and colors for the nodes. As I'm completely new to forest package, if this information is also included, it would have been nice.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Maybe you could create a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) based on the linked question and then point out what exactly you would like to change. This would make it easer to help you, since although the linked answer gives you a nice explanation how to draw a basic taxonomy tree, it is of course still different from what you show in the picture.

Comment: Also related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398495/change-color-of-forest-block